# How to select text after an element with jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have a paragraph:

```
<p>red orange yellow green blue indigo violet</p>
```

I need to wrap the ending text in something that I can hide/show on click, like so:

```
<p>red orange yellow green 
  <a href="#">...Show More</a>
  <span="unhideme">blue indigo violet</span>
</p>
```

This is how far i've gotten:

```
<p>red orange yellow green 
  <a href="#">...Show More</a> 
  blue indigo violet
</p>
```

Is there some way to say "select all text after the a tag and wrap it in a span" with jquery? Or some other solution to generating a "Read More" button with jquery?

Comment: What stops you from wraping the text in a span to begin with?

Comment: Show us the JS so we can see how you are creating these if your are dynamically and how youre adding the a tag

Comment: are you creating these dynamically?

Comment: Yes, they are being created dynamically. I'm using a cms (modx) so basically, the client pastes their paragraph in the cms, and I need to create some "read more" functionality once it gets too long. I'm using a modx thing to add the a tag after a certain number of characters.

Comment: It looks like you are trying this order: 1) find the paragraph 2) add an anchor after x words 3) wrap the remainder in a span. It would probably be better to swap that around: 1) find the paragraph 2) split the text inside after x words 3) wrap the second part in a span 4) add the anchor before the new span

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just parse through the HTML of the p tag. Start by getting it all then breaking it up then just append the a and span tags before making it the HTML again.

```
var allText = $("p").html();
var firstHalf = allText.substring(0,INDEX AT WHICH YOU WOULD LIKE TO STOP);
var secondHalf = allText.substring(INDEX AT WHICH YOU WOULD LIKE TO STOP+1);
var newHTML = firstHalf + '<a href="#">...Show More</a><span class="unhideme">' + secondhalf + "</span>";

$("p").html(newHTML);
```

Comment: Ooo this looks like it will work! But, what does "INDEX AT WHICH YOU WOULD LIKE TO STOP" refer to? What do I put there?

Comment: That is the number of characters that you would like to show. Any after the integer you put in there will be put in the read more section. @Shonna

Answer (score 0):

This *maybe* a start:

```
$('p').each(function () {
    var $p = $(this);
    var words = $p.html().split(' ');
    $p.html('');

    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        $p.append(words[i] + ' ');
    }

    if (words.length > 3) {
        var htmlStr = '<a href="#">...Show More</a><span class="unhideme">';
        for (var i = 3; i < words.length; i++) {
            htmlStr += words[i] + ' ';
        }
        htmlStr += '</span>';

        $p.append(htmlStr);
    }
}); 

$('p').on('click', 'a', function () {
     $(this).hide().next().show();
});
```

That `3` is hard-coded so you may want to change that. It basically represents how many items you want shown.

**OR**

If you want a plug-in to do all the dirty work for you check out [trunk8](http://jrvis.com/trunk8/) for jquery.